# How to initialize a float variable to be infinity in C language ？

Tags: c, floating-point, initialization

I want to initialize a variable in C language to be the plus infinity or minus infinity, how can I do that ? The below fails:

float plus_inf = 0.0/0.0;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try

```
#include <math.h>
....
float x = INFINITY;
```

According to the standard:

> The macro
>
> **INFINITY**
>
> expands to a constant expression of type **float** representing positive or unsigned
> infinity, if available; else to a positive constant of type **float** that overflows at translation time.

Comment: Just a note: this requires C99 support.

Comment: yes, thank you. but I have to use C89 in some platforms.

Comment: For C89 use `HUGE_VAL` also from `<math.h>`

Answer (score 2):

`0.0/0.0` is a `nan` (not a number), as an alternative to `INFINITY` (c89 and earlier) try:

```
float plus_inf = 1.0/0.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Macro Infinity is defined under  library.

float variable = INFINITY;